# Why in a for loop of HTML class elements, the variables like i, j, k shows undefined?

Tags: javascript, arrays, for-loop, object, dom

See my code of multi level of for loops and why the variables of j, k undefined. But only i works.
I am making a three levels of product variations.

First loop variable is i, it works. Second loop variable is j, doesn't work. Third loop variable is k, don't know if it works.

```
//starts code for product variable
    if (document.getElementById('variants')) {
        let variants = JSON.parse(document.getElementById('variants').innerHTML);
        let variableForm = document.getElementById('variable-form');
        let baseName = document.getElementById('base-name');
        let price = document.querySelector('span#price');
        let stock = document.querySelector('span#stock');
        let SKU = document.getElementById('sku');
        let quantity = document.getElementById('quantity');
        let baseVariants = variants.filter(variant => variant.base === "");
        baseVariants.forEach(variant => {
            baseName.innerHTML = variant.name + ": ";
            variableForm.innerHTML += `<input class="base-radio" style="width: 40px; display: inline;" type="radio" name="baseVariableName" value="${variant.value}"><label style="width: 40px; display: inline;">${variant.value}</label>`;
        });
        let baseRadioClass = document.getElementsByClassName('base-radio');
        for(let i = 0; i < baseRadioClass.length; i++){
            baseRadioClass[i].addEventListener('click', changeContent);
            function changeContent() {
                price.innerHTML = baseVariants[i].price;
                stock.innerHTML = baseVariants[i].stock;
                sku.value = baseVariants[i].SKU;
                quantity.max = baseVariants[i].stock;
            
                let secondLevel = variants.filter(variant => variant.base === baseVariants[i].SKU);
                
                if (secondLevel.length === 0) {
                    document.getElementById('secondLevel-form').style.display = 'none';
                    document.getElementById('thirdLevel-form').style.display = 'none';
                }
                if(secondLevel.length > 0){
                    document.getElementById('secondLevel-form').style.display = 'block';
                    document.getElementsByName('secondVariableName').forEach(sec => sec.checked = false)
    
                }
            }
            
            
        
        //second level
        
            let secondLevel = variants.filter(variant => variant.base === baseVariants[i].SKU);
            let secondLevelForm = document.getElementById('secondLevel-form');
            let secondLevelName = document.getElementById('secondLevel-name');
            secondLevel.forEach(variant => {
                secondLevelName.innerHTML = variant.name + ": ";
                secondLevelForm.innerHTML += `<input class="second-radio" style="width: 40px; display: inline;" type="radio" name="secondVariableName" value="${variant.value}"><label style="width: 40px; display: inline;">${variant.value}</label>`;
            });
            let secondRadioClass = document.getElementsByClassName('second-radio');
            for (let j = 0; j < secondRadioClass.length; j++) {
                secondRadioClass[j].addEventListener('click', changeContent());
                function changeContent() {
                    price.innerHTML = secondLevel[j].price;
                    stock.innerHTML = secondLevel[j].stock;
                    sku.value = secondLevel[j].SKU;
                    quantity.max = secondLevel[j].stock;
                    let thirdLevel = secondLevel.filter(variant => variant.base === secondLevel[j].SKU);
                    console.log(thirdLevel);
                    if (thirdLevel.length === 0) {
                        document.getElementById('thirdLevel-form').style.display = 'none';
                    }
                    if (thirdLevel.length > 0) {
                        document.getElementById('thirdLevel-form').style.display = 'block';
                        document.getElementsByName('thirdVariableName').forEach(sec => sec.checked = false)
                    }
                }


                //third level
                let thirdLevel = secondLevel.filter(variant => variant.base === secondLevel[j].SKU);
                let thirdLevelForm = document.getElementById('thirdLevel-form');
                let thirdLevelName = document.getElementById('thirdLevel-name');
                thirdLevel.forEach(variant =>{
                    thirdLevelName.innerHTML = variant.name + ": ";
                    thirdLevelForm.innerHTML += `<input class="third-radio" style="width: 40px; display: inline;" type="radio" name="thirdVariableName" value="${variant.value}"><label style="width: 40px; display: inline;">${variant.value}</label>`;
                })
                let thirdRadioClass = document.getElementsByClassName('third-radio');
                for (let k = 0; k < thirdRadioClass.length; k++) {
                    thirdRadioClass[k].addEventListener('click', changeContent);
                    function changeContent() {
                        price.innerHTML = thirdLevel[k].price;
                        stock.innerHTML = thirdLevel[k].stock;
                        sku.value = thirdLevel[k].SKU;
                        quantity.max = thirdLevel[k].stock;
                    }
                }
                
            }
        }
```

HTML code is probably fine. I think I am missing some points about for loop that I don't know.
HTML ejs code

```
                <!-- variable codes -->
                <% if(product.variants.length >= 0){ %>
                    <div id="variants" style="display: none;">
                    <%= JSON.stringify(product.variants) %>
                    </div>
                <% } %>
                
                <div id="variable-form">
                    <label id="base-name" style="font-weight: bold;">
                        
                    </label>
                </div>
                <div id="secondLevel-form">
                    <label id="secondLevel-name" style="font-weight: bold;"></label>
                </div>
                <div id="thirdLevel-form">
                
                    <label id="thirdLevel-name" style="font-weight: bold;"></label>
                
                </div>
    
        <p>Price: <span id="price"><%= product.price %></span></p>
        <p>Stock Left:<span id="stock"><%= product.stock %></span></p>
    
        <form action="/add-to-cart" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">
            <label style="display: inline;">Quantity: </label> <input id="quantity" name="quantity" type="number"
                style="width: 40px; display: inline;" max="<%= product.stock %>" min="1" required>
            <input type="hidden" id="product-id" name="product" value="<%= product.id%>">
            <input type="hidden" id="sku" name="SKU" value="<%= product.SKU %>">
            <br><br><label>Upload a design of your choice</label><input style="width: 150px;" type="file" id="imageCover" name="imageCover">
            
            <input type="submit" id="add-cart" class="add-cart" value="Add to cart">
            <a id="message-info" href="/cart">Added to cart. Visit cart</a>
        </form>
```

This code adds radio buttons on the fly to the html code.

Comment: Add which line triggers the error and error content.

Comment: Nevermind... You use a variable inside a dynamic created function changeContent(). Short answer is: move funcion changeContent() outside of those for each. Second thing, make it support an input parameter `changeContent(j)`. These two things should fix your problem.

Comment: Or.. remove `function changeContent() {` + `}` its end from everywhere.... It doesn't looks like it has a well defined purpose, so that's what it screws your code.

Comment: There are three definitions of `changeContent` in the code, one of which is called immediately and the return value assigned to an event listener. Just use an anonymous function and assign it to the event listener directly.

Comment: Anonymous function does not work

Answer (score 0):

Remove changeContent() lines from your code (I commented them for you). If you really want to use a function, declare it outside of those foreach() and make it accept an input parameter.

```
var baseVariants = [750, 280]
function changeContent(index){
     console.log(baseVariants[index].stock);
}

for (let i = 0; i < baseVariants.length ; i++){
    changeContent(i);
}
```

Here is your code corrected.

```
//starts code for product variable
if (document.getElementById('variants')) {
    let variants = JSON.parse(document.getElementById('variants').innerHTML);
    let variableForm = document.getElementById('variable-form');
    let baseName = document.getElementById('base-name');
    let price = document.querySelector('span#price');
    let stock = document.querySelector('span#stock');
    let SKU = document.getElementById('sku');
    let quantity = document.getElementById('quantity');
    let baseVariants = variants.filter(variant => variant.base === "");
    baseVariants.forEach(variant => {
        baseName.innerHTML = variant.name + ": ";
        variableForm.innerHTML += `<input class="base-radio" style="width: 40px; display: inline;" type="radio" name="baseVariableName" value="${variant.value}"><label style="width: 40px; display: inline;">${variant.value}</label>`;
    });
    let baseRadioClass = document.getElementsByClassName('base-radio');
    
    for(let i = 0; i < baseRadioClass.length; i++){
        baseRadioClass[i].addEventListener('click', changeContent);
        
        // There is no good reason for this function to exist in your code....
        //function changeContent() {
        
            price.innerHTML = baseVariants[i].price;
            stock.innerHTML = baseVariants[i].stock;
            sku.value = baseVariants[i].SKU;
            quantity.max = baseVariants[i].stock;
        
            let secondLevel = variants.filter(variant => variant.base === baseVariants[i].SKU);
            
            if (secondLevel.length === 0) {
                document.getElementById('secondLevel-form').style.display = 'none';
                document.getElementById('thirdLevel-form').style.display = 'none';
            }
            if(secondLevel.length > 0){
                document.getElementById('secondLevel-form').style.display = 'block';
                document.getElementsByName('secondVariableName').forEach(sec => sec.checked = false)

            }
        //}
        
        
    
        //second level
    
        let secondLevel = variants.filter(variant => variant.base === baseVariants[i].SKU);
        let secondLevelForm = document.getElementById('secondLevel-form');
        let secondLevelName = document.getElementById('secondLevel-name');
        secondLevel.forEach(variant => {
            secondLevelName.innerHTML = variant.name + ": ";
            secondLevelForm.innerHTML += `<input class="second-radio" style="width: 40px; display: inline;" type="radio" name="secondVariableName" value="${variant.value}"><label style="width: 40px; display: inline;">${variant.value}</label>`;
        });
        let secondRadioClass = document.getElementsByClassName('second-radio');
        
        for (let j = 0; j < secondRadioClass.length; j++) {
        
            secondRadioClass[j].addEventListener('click', changeContent());
            
            // There is no good reason for this function to exist in your code....
            // You also overload it many times
            //function changeContent() {
                price.innerHTML = secondLevel[j].price;
                stock.innerHTML = secondLevel[j].stock;
                sku.value = secondLevel[j].SKU;
                quantity.max = secondLevel[j].stock;
                let thirdLevel = secondLevel.filter(variant => variant.base === secondLevel[j].SKU);
                console.log(thirdLevel);
                if (thirdLevel.length === 0) {
                    document.getElementById('thirdLevel-form').style.display = 'none';
                }
                if (thirdLevel.length > 0) {
                    document.getElementById('thirdLevel-form').style.display = 'block';
                    document.getElementsByName('thirdVariableName').forEach(sec => sec.checked = false)
                }
            //}


            //third level
            let thirdLevel = secondLevel.filter(variant => variant.base === secondLevel[j].SKU);
            let thirdLevelForm = document.getElementById('thirdLevel-form');
            let thirdLevelName = document.getElementById('thirdLevel-name');
            thirdLevel.forEach(variant =>{
                thirdLevelName.innerHTML = variant.name + ": ";
                thirdLevelForm.innerHTML += `<input class="third-radio" style="width: 40px; display: inline;" type="radio" name="thirdVariableName" value="${variant.value}"><label style="width: 40px; display: inline;">${variant.value}</label>`;
            })
            let thirdRadioClass = document.getElementsByClassName('third-radio');
            for (let k = 0; k < thirdRadioClass.length; k++) {
                thirdRadioClass[k].addEventListener('click', changeContent);
                
                // There is no good reason for this function to exist in your code....
                //function changeContent() {
                    price.innerHTML = thirdLevel[k].price;
                    stock.innerHTML = thirdLevel[k].stock;
                    sku.value = thirdLevel[k].SKU;
                    quantity.max = thirdLevel[k].stock;
                //}
            }
            
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

So, I fixed it. Answering my own question. What solved it is just a few simple if statements. I just had to see if the quantity of second levels and third levels greater than zero. And it worked.

Then also another mistake in third level, I was filtering secondlevel by secondlevel instead of variants by secondlevel base.

The correct code...

```
if (document.getElementById('variants')) {
    let variants = JSON.parse(document.getElementById('variants').innerHTML);
    let variableForm = document.getElementById('variable-form');
    let baseName = document.getElementById('base-name');
    let price = document.querySelector('span#price');
    let stock = document.querySelector('span#stock');
    let SKU = document.getElementById('sku');
    let quantity = document.getElementById('quantity');

    let baseVariants = variants.filter((variant) => variant.base === '');

    baseVariants.forEach((variant) => {
      baseName.innerHTML = variant.name + ': ';
      variableForm.innerHTML += `<input class="base-radio" style="width: 40px; display: inline;" type="radio" name="baseVariableName" value="${variant.value}" required="true"><label style="width: 40px; display: inline;">${variant.value}</label>`;
    });

    let baseRadioClass = document.getElementsByClassName('base-radio');
    for (let i = 0; i < baseRadioClass.length; i++) {
      baseRadioClass[i].addEventListener('click', changeContent);

      function changeContent() {
        price.innerHTML = baseVariants[i].price;
        stock.innerHTML = baseVariants[i].stock;
        sku.value = baseVariants[i].SKU;
        quantity.max = baseVariants[i].stock;

        let secondLevel = variants.filter(
          (variant) => variant.base === baseVariants[i].SKU
        );

        if (secondLevel.length === 0) {
          document.getElementById('secondLevel-form').style.display = 'none';
          document.getElementById('thirdLevel-form').style.display = 'none';
        }
        if (secondLevel.length > 0) {
          document.getElementById('secondLevel-form').style.display = 'block';
          document
            .getElementsByName('secondVariableName')
            .forEach((sec) => (sec.checked = false));
        }
      }
    }

    //second level
    for (let i = 0; i < baseRadioClass.length; i++) {
      let secondLevel = variants.filter(
        (variant) => variant.base === baseVariants[i].SKU
      );
      if (secondLevel.length > 0) {
        let secondLevelForm = document.getElementById('secondLevel-form');
        let secondLevelName = document.getElementById('secondLevel-name');

        secondLevel.forEach((variant) => {
          secondLevelName.innerHTML = variant.name + ': ';
          secondLevelForm.innerHTML += `<input class="second-radio" style="width: 40px; display: inline;" type="radio" name="secondVariableName" value="${variant.value}" required="true"><label style="width: 40px; display: inline;">${variant.value}</label>`;
        });

        let secondRadioClass = document.getElementsByClassName('second-radio');

        for (let j = 0; j < secondRadioClass.length; j++) {
          secondRadioClass[j].addEventListener('click', changeSecContent);

          function changeSecContent() {
            price.innerHTML = secondLevel[j].price;
            stock.innerHTML = secondLevel[j].stock;
            sku.value = secondLevel[j].SKU;
            quantity.max = secondLevel[j].stock;

            let thirdLevel = variants.filter(
              (variant) => variant.base === secondLevel[j].SKU
            );

            if (thirdLevel.length === 0) {
              document.getElementById('thirdLevel-form').style.display = 'none';
            }
            if (thirdLevel.length > 0) {
              document.getElementById('thirdLevel-form').style.display =
                'block';
              document
                .getElementsByName('thirdVariableName')
                .forEach((sec) => (sec.checked = false));
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }

    //third level
    for (let i = 0; i < baseRadioClass.length; i++) {
      let secondLevel = variants.filter(
        (variant) => variant.base === baseVariants[i].SKU
      );
      if (secondLevel.length > 0) {
        let secondRadioClass = document.getElementsByClassName('second-radio');

        for (let j = 0; j < secondRadioClass.length; j++) {
          let thirdLevel = variants.filter(
            (variant) => variant.base === secondLevel[j].SKU
          );

          if (thirdLevel.length > 0) {
            let thirdLevelForm = document.getElementById('thirdLevel-form');
            let thirdLevelName = document.getElementById('thirdLevel-name');

            thirdLevel.forEach((variant) => {
              thirdLevelName.innerHTML = variant.name + ': ';
              thirdLevelForm.innerHTML += `<input class="third-radio" style="width: 40px; display: inline;" type="radio" name="thirdVariableName" value="${variant.value}" required><label style="width: 40px; display: inline;">${variant.value}</label>`;
            });

            let thirdRadioClass = document.getElementsByClassName(
              'third-radio'
            );

            for (let k = 0; k < thirdRadioClass.length; k++) {
              thirdRadioClass[k].addEventListener('click', changeThirdContent);

              function changeThirdContent() {
                price.innerHTML = thirdLevel[k].price;
                stock.innerHTML = thirdLevel[k].stock;
                sku.value = thirdLevel[k].SKU;
                quantity.max = thirdLevel[k].stock;
              }
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
```

If someone can refactor this code with a better version, I would love that.